# Angular - how to page refresh to original landing URL which includes parameterized path name

Tags: angular

I am a newbie to Angular, my current setup:

index.html

```
 <base href="/">
```

landing url:

```
 http://localhost/
```

Now we have a need to support multiple clients, and would like to add a pathname to the landing url

```
 https://localhost/client/:clientId
 example: /client/1, /client/2, etc.
```

How do I control the page refresh to the exact original landing url, override base url.

I have tried various solutions - window.location.href, and Angular Location service. It appears that Angular just ignores what I was doing. Currently I have this event handler, does not work either, it reloads to the current route, '/#view'.

@HostListener("window:beforeunload", ["$event"]) pageRefreshHandler(event: Event) {

```
  var link = document.createElement('a');
  //link.setAttribute('href', this.appService.baseUrl);
  link.setAttribute('href', 'http://localhost:4200/client/1');
  link.setAttribute('target', '_blank');
  document.body.appendChild(link);
  link.click();

  event.preventDefault();
```

}

My other problem, angular-cli complained

Argument of type 'Location' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.

for this line:

```
  link.setAttribute('href', this.appService.baseUrl);
```

Any idea what I did wrong here?
Thanks.

Comment: Hello and Welcome to Stack Overflow! So when you press `F5` or reload page in some other way you want to stay on route `/client/1`?

Comment: Correct. Another client, #2, would refresh to /client/2. II don't want to change base url  as specified in index.html  though, because it might mean lots more changes, if possible at all. Thanks.

Comment: Please ignore the error message I received: Argument of type 'Location' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
Indeed, this.appService.baseUrl was of Location type. Issue fixed. Thanks.